# How do return the path and the optimal moves?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def solve_puzzle(board):
    '''Initializes Variables'''
    index = 0
    path = []
    num_moves = float('inf')
    return find_optimal_path(board, index, path, num_moves)

def find_optimal_path(board, index, path, num_moves):
    '''Finds most optimal path'''
    if len(board) == 1:
        return [0], 0
    if index == len(board) - 1: return 0

    opt_moves = num_moves 

    path.append(index)

    forward = (index + board[index])

    backward = (index - board[index])

    for move in (forward, backward):
        if move < 0 or move >= len(board):
            continue
        else:
            if move not in path:
                num_moves = 1 + find_optimal_path(board, move, path, num_moves)
                if num_moves < opt_moves:
                    opt_moves = num_moves
    return opt_moves


print(solve_puzzle([8, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 7, 4, 4, 6]))


#Output should be

#[0, 8, 4, 3, 1, 9], 5
```

Hi I need to return the most optimal path to get to the end of the list, and while my opt_moves (tells how many moves it takes to optimally reach the end). The logic to check the optimal amount of moves is correct, but I do not know how to return the path as well. Example output is in the last 3 lines.